# center two DIVs when shrunken down and fitted in a new line

Tags: html, css

I have 4 DIVs fitted in a row which have width:50% and are floating left so that two of them fit in a line. They have to have a min-width so the content can be shown completely. When I make the page smaller I only have one div in a line left (which is what I want) but its not centered any more...

I want those DIVs always to be centered! Can anyone help me?

HTML code:

```
    <div class="row">
                <div class="app-screen-div">
                    <div class="app-screen">
                        <img src="images/deal_list.png" alt="Deal Liste">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="app-screen-div">
                    <div class="app-screen">
                        <img src="images/code_scan.png" alt="Scan">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="app-screen-div">
                    <div class="app-screen">
                        <img src="images/deals_begonnen.png" alt="Started Deals">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="app-screen-div">
                    <div class="app-screen">
                        <img src="images/enter_deal.png" alt="Enter Deal">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .row {
margin:auto;
padding:auto;
}

    .app-screen-div{
float:left;
width:50%;
min-width:280px;
margin:auto;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
}

    .app-screen{
border-style:solid;
border-radius:5px;
padding: 1px;
border: 1px solid grey;
background-color:#ff5253;
width:280px;
margin:auto;
}

    .app-screen > img {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` and I used `text-align: center`. Take a look at the example at http://jsfiddle.net/rqh0ompa/4/. Please note that you will have to enlarge the Result section quite  a bit in order to see the change/

Comment: thank you, that fixrd it! you only have to add "text-align:center;" to the row-div!